Fixing a set without loss of generality for an injection/bijection
I am hoping to prove the following, without leveraging the Axiom of Choice:

Let $|A|\le|B|$ (resp. $|A|=|B|$) and $S\subseteq A\cap B$. Then, there exists an injection (resp. bijection) $f\colon A\to B$ such that $f$ fixes $S$; that is, $f|_S=\iota$ is the identity.

It's easier intuitively for me to consider the bijective case, which is clearly equivalent by renaming $B$ to the image of $A$. My constructive proof assumes a bijection $g\colon A\to B$ and constructs
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,\quad\quad&\text{if $x\in S$},\\g(x)&\text{if $x\notin S$ and $g(x)\notin S$},\\g(g(x)),&\text{if $x\notin S$ and $g(x)\in S$.}\end{cases}$$
Is there a more elegant proof that $f$ is indeed bijective without discussing all 9 possible scenarios for, e.g., injectivity? Or is there altogether a better argument to prove the statement above?
Edit: Thanks to @lulu for pointing out that my choice of $f$ does not work. In general, is there a way to prove the statement without AC?

Well, that doesn't work.  Say $A={a,b,c}$, $B={a,b,d}$ and $S={a,b}$ with $f(a)=b, f(b)=d,f(c)=a$.,

Should add,  I assume that you wrote $f$ instead of $g$ in the definition of $f$ by accident

Thank @lulu, I fixed the formulation of $g$, and thanks for pointing out my error. In general, is there an easy way, preferably without AC, to prove the statement of interest?

Consider the case where $|A|=|B|$ and $B\subsetneqq A$ and $S=A\cap B=B$. For instance, $A={0,1,2,3,\dots}$ and $S=B={1,2,3,\dots}$.

If $|A|<|B|$, then let $A'=A-S,B'=B-S$.  Fix $S$.  Now, axiomatically, we must either have an injection from $A'\to B'$ or from $B'\to A'$ (or both).  Either of the last two cases would imply $|A|=|B|$, a contradiction.  Thus there is an injection from $A'\to B'$ and we are done.  The equal case is similar.

@lulu What do you mean by "axiomatically..."? This is a consequence of the axiom of choice, but the OP wants a proof that does not use choice.

@lulu I don't think "the equal case is similar." Because it's false.

@AlexKruckman In case $|A|\lt|B|$ the proposition holds in ZFC as noted in lulu's comment, but is not provable in ZF. Suppose $D$ is an infinite set such that $|D|$ is incomparable with $\aleph_0$. Let $A=\mathbb Z$ and $B=\mathbb N\cup D$ and $S=\mathbb N\subseteq A\cap B$; then $|A|\lt|B|$ but there is no injection $f:A\to B$ such that $f(S)=S$.

@user14111  Ah!  Good catch.

This is not true. Let $A = \mathbb{N}$, $B = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. Let $S = B = A \cap B$. Then $|A| = |B|$. Suppose $f : A \to B$ is an injection fixing $S$. Then $f(f(0)) = f(0)$, so $f(0) = 0$. But $0 \notin B$. Contradiction.
